# No se reconoce o no se puede tener acceso al miembro InputBindings

Tags: c#, windows, wpf, xaml

Tengo una interfaz desarrollada con WPF (xaml y c#) y quiero añadir este keybinding pero me sale el error del título, ¿alguna idea de qué puede estar pasando?

```
<Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
```

Comment: Puedes poner el Xaml completo? El problema puede estar en la estructura. Basicamente...esta dentro de un `<Window>` ese código?

Comment: Está dentro de otro UserControl que engloba a toda la interfaz, aparte de eso tengo un '''<UserControl.Resources>''' y un '''<Grid>'''. Siento no poder ser más específica. Creo que me falta algún espacio de nombres, pero no sé qué puede ser

Comment: Si esta en un UserControl, prueba con `<UserControl.InputBindings>`

Comment: Mil gracias! Era eso, el inputBinding tiene que ser del tipo que hereda, es decir si su ancestro es un datagrid el inputBinding será `<DataGrid.InputBindings>`. Como en este caso su ancestro era UserControl, no aceptaba que intentase meter un `<Window.InputBindings>`. Espero que sirva!